# Windows 8.1's interpreter does not accept FOR input file

Tags: batch-file

I am relearning DOS/batch & seems different.
Script should create a text file (it does, verified) then read it line by line looking for a beginning word and discarding lines thru that line as it builds TMP.txt.
It should then create a file of remaining lines up to and including a finishing word and ignore the remainder.
Then it will look for a line containing a specific word.
Problem: I get ("inFile.txt") was unexpected.  The reams of text I have pulled down into my reference directory has not been helpful as it appears (does't it always) correct from what I expect.
Here is the script to and a bit after that point:

```
REM Append a final line to input text
echo IDSS >> inFile.txt

REM Bookend the node's text with BEGwd and FINwd.
REM Read inFile.txt file- Ignore %%A if BEGwd not found,
REM else write remaining lines to TMP.

for /F "tokens=*" %%A ("inFile.txt") DO (      <<---- Problem line
if "*%BEGwd%*" == "*%%A*" echo "%%A" >> TMP.txt
)


REM Read TMP look for FINwd- Write non-%%B lines to TMP2
REM until FINwd
    for /F "tokens=*" %%B ("TMP.txt") DO (   
    if "*%FINwd%*" == "*%%B*" goto SEARCH
    echo "%%B" >> TMP2.txt
    )
```

Am also unsure if batch will accept my IF command compare with *'s?
Appreciating any assistance there too.

Comment: Why do you want to learn an outdated technology? I recommend you spend some time learning powershell instead.

Comment: Regular expressions are not allowed in `if` statements. Please provide examples of what you are trying to do - your current approach will not work.

Comment: Don't waste your time with Powershell. If you try and use it on a system where it isn't enabled, the script won't run, which makes it useless for a work environment with any sort of security policy. Also, the entire language is unnecessarily verbose.

Answer (score 0):

for /F "tokens=*" %%A ("inFile.txt") DO (      <<---- Problem line

Correct syntax is `for /F "`**USEBACKQ**`tokens=*" %%A`**IN**`("inFile.txt") DO (`

the `usebackq` option is required because you have "quoted your filename".